# extended class is not of parent type?

Tags: java, android

Sorry for my noob question.I have a class named of type Card.
If I used another class that extends Card named BookHeader.Why I can not use it in a List?here is my code:

```
    package com.peomtime.tosca.peomtime.Databse;

import android.content.Context;

import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.internal.Card;
import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.internal.CardHeader;

/**
 * Created by CrazyVirus on 2015-02-06.
 */
public class PartHeader extends Card {
    private String Title;
    private String ID;
    private String BookID;
    private Context context;
    private CardHeader header;

    public void setBookID(String BookID)
    {
        this.BookID = BookID;
    }
    public String getBookID(){return this.BookID;}

    public void setTitle(String Title)
    {
        this.Title = Title;
        header.setTitle(Title);
        this.addCardHeader(header);
    }
    public String getTitle(){return this.Title;}

    public void setID(String ID)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
    public String getID(){return this.ID;}

    public PartHeader(Context c){
        super(c);
        this.context =c;
        header = new CardHeader(context);

    }

    public Card getCard(){

        return this;
    }
}
```

As it shows my class extends Card.So How can I use it in these code

```
List<PartHeader> BookPartList = db.getAllBookParts(BookID);
BookPartAdaptet mBookPartAdapter = new BookPartAdaptet(this, BookPartList );
```

here is `BookPartAdaptet`

```
  public BookPartAdaptet(Context context, List<Card> cards) {


    super(context, cards);
    data=cards;
   // inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  //  activity = context.getApplicationContext();

}
```

I get error in this line

```
BookPartAdaptet mBookPartAdapter = new BookPartAdaptet(this, BookPartList );
```

that says `BookPartList` myst be of type `List<Card>` not `List<PartHeader >`

I think because of extended class I can use it as parents type?If I can not how Can do it?
Thank you for your help.And sorry for my noob question:(

Comment: Why are you defining list with specific type i.e. `List<PartHeader >` then why not `List<Card> list  = ..`?

Comment: @almasshaikh Because I need a new extended calss of `Card ` and BookPartAdaptet needs a List<Card> and I have List<PartHeader > ,Can not I cast them?or things like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to try something like this:

```java
public BookPartAdaptet(Context context, List<? extends Card> cards) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You beat me. An explanation for this is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs

Comment: It seems this is what I need.When I use List<? extends Card> it meens that I can use extended classes?then what will happen next?do I face a problem when another class needs Card and I give them PartHeader that is extended from Card?

Comment: @Axel I used your sugested way and it fixed but now I have the same problem in `super(context, cards);` should I then convert List<PartHeader> to List<Card>?

Comment: As described in the link provided by @Axel, passing `List<? extends Card>` means that you can use any element in the list as though it were a `Card`, even if its true type is any subclass of `Card`. If you give a `PartHeader` object to another method that is expecting a `Card`, then that is still fine. I'm not sure what you mean by the `super(context,cards);` part; we would need more details to understand the problem.

Comment: @jadhachem Thank you for your help,you know I have extended  `BookPartAdaptet` from another class and the `BookPartAdaptet` method is overrided so in `super(context,cards);` I still forced to add `card` type

Comment: Oh I see. Does the corresponding constructor in the super-class of `BookPartAdaptet` also take `(Context context, List<Card> cards)` argument? If so maybe you should also make it `List<? extends Card> cards`.

Answer (score 1):

You should change you definition of BookPartAdaptet to the follwoing so you can pass the list of any subclass of Cards

```
public BookPartAdaptet(Context context, List<? extends Card> cards){
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked but I get error in super(context, cards); How can I cast my list?is there any method?

Comment: what is the card type is super class?

Comment: it is a super class that is from CardAdapter